# Github action is showing error when there is a private repository in the package json

Tags: npm, ssh, github-actions

I have this line in the dependency section of package.json file.

```
"<repository>": "git+ssh://git@github.com:<userName>/<repository>"
```

I have setup ssh in my github account and when I do npm install locally, it works correctly. As a new requirement, I am using github actions to automate this workflow.
This is the part of the yml file

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: webfactory/ssh-agent
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
        with:
            ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - name: Set up Node Js version as ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        
      - name: Install The Dependencies
        run: npm install
```

Install The Dependencies step is failing and this error is seen in github actions

```
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<repository>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
```

Thanks in advance for any solutions.

Comment: Is the repository private?

Comment: Yes it is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u can solve this buy publishing the repo, plz try that and let me know if it's worked